# device_calendar 0.1.0 plugin for flutter limit permission for calendar access

Tags: plugins, dart, flutter

We are using the `device_calendar 0.1.0` plugin for flutter and we want to limit the access permission for calendars question to once only.

Is there a way to achieve this or does this require the question be asked every time? Seems like it would be annoying to ask multiple times while navigating an app.

Code for checking permission:

```
void _retrieveCalendars() async {
try {
  var permissionsGranted = await _deviceCalendarPlugin.hasPermissions();
  if (permissionsGranted.isSuccess && !permissionsGranted.data) {
    permissionsGranted = await _deviceCalendarPlugin.requestPermissions();
    if (!permissionsGranted.isSuccess || !permissionsGranted.data) {
      return;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

By your code I can assume it's checking if the user already gave the permissions to your app, by defining a variable with that status:

```dart
var permissionsGranted = await _deviceCalendarPlugin.hasPermissions();
```

and using to define when it will be needed to ask the permissions or not ask again  on the line:

```dart
if (permissionsGranted.isSuccess && !permissionsGranted.data) {
```

but if that is not working I would advise you to test the [official example](https://github.com/builttoroam/flutter_plugins/tree/develop/device_calendar/example_app), that makes the same check.

Comment: I'm using the official example, I guess my question is if they accept it will it work every time after if I store it or does it have to be asked everytime? Its my first shot at accessing a device calendar and I wasnt sure.

Comment: No, the `requestPermissions()` handle that for you, and once it's accepted it's stored the info of the acceptance for you app, so it doesn't ask again.